# How to simulate slow server response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I want to test some User interface features for when AJAX requests take longer time. Is there an easy way to do this when using Rails 4 as server?

Basically I would want to continiously have each AJAX request delayed by 1-2 sec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using an http proxy and delay requests there. I myself use [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). It can impose all kinds of limits on your connection: delays, slowness, random failures, etc.

[image]

Fun fact: I was testing exactly the same thing once (slow internet) and forgot to remove the limit on the connection. I then spent half a day being very frustrated by unusually slow internet. It was so slow that I could see jpeg load line by line. Even made a call to my ISP and complained, I think. Imagine my embarrassment after I found the reason. :)

Comment: plus one for a fun fact, call to ISP is epic. The "only for selected host" option works with `localhost:3000` ?

Comment: @Зелёный: even better than that. For a "selected host" you can specify host, port, path and query. All of those with wildcards! :)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty method...

Put this in your ruby ajax controller method:

```
1e8.to_i.times {}
```

or make it a before_action in application_controller.rb.

```
before_action -> { 1e8.to_i.times {} if Rails.env == 'development' }
```